# Code edit preview jumping around

Tags: bug, edits, scrolling

When editing posts that at first contain nothing but a huge code block, the scrollbar next to the code block always jumps to the beginning when I make edits to the code.  This can get extremely annoying.  Does this happen with every code block like this?

(This happens on Google Chrome version 25.0.1364.97)

Live demo:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmFp5cGAl_s

Comment: Can we see the question/answer you are talking about?

Comment: What browser/version are you seeing this in?

Comment: Took the liberty to add a demo, hope you don't mind. If you do, feel free to roll back. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Side question. Which tool do you use for capturing screen video?

Comment: @hims056 you can see it in the end of my vid, anyway it's http://camstudio.org/ :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is kind of unavoidable, because the preview area HTML is completely rerendered as you're making changes. Since the code block you scrolled is no longer the code block that's actually there, the browser is unable to preserve your scroll position.

Comment: It's possible with some JavaScript, it can detect the caret position and try to restore it in the preview scroll. Not trivial, but should be possible.

Comment: The OP is modifying the contents of the code block they're scrolling though, so I don't see this working in any sort of reliable way.

Comment: See my demo. At least in the simple case of just adding characters to the end of the code should preserve the scroll in my opinion.